# How to make second monitor work independently?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

Today I purchased a 32 inch lg monitor and connected that as my main monitor and used second monitor as secondary under multiple monitors and extended display using win+P.

The problem is when I open anything like browser in second monitor it opens in my first monitor, if that is how it is going to be than what is the point of second monitor? Can you please help me fix this issue. What am i doing wrong?

P.S. I have already identified both monitors as 1 and 2. Thing are opening fine in first monitor. I just think second monitor should work independently of monitor 1.

Comment: i think i got it. I have to drag windows to second monitor to work independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows open news programs in the main display (monitor 1 in your case). You can then drag the window or use <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>left</kbd> (or <kbd>right</kbd>) to move it where you want.

If you then close the window, it should remember where it was last opened as well as its size.

You might have unexpected behaviour if you change your monitors often (say a laptop that you sometimes connect to a second monitor).

I'm not sure what you exactly mean by *"work independently"* but you can also add  the taskbar to your extended display so you don't need to move your mouse to the first one: right click on the taskbar, `taskbar settings`, and in section *Multiple display*: `show taskbar on all displays` on/off